# Sell asset to balance the portfolio

Tags: algebras

Given:

- a portfolio with only two assets (A and B)
- they respective balances (Balance<sub>A</sub> and Balance<sub>B</sub>)
- the function $C_{AtoB}$ that converts A into B:

  - $C_{AtoB}(x, q, cr) = x(1 - cr)q$, where

    - x = the amount of Asset A to be convert
    - q = the quotation of Asset A
    - cr = the convertion rate cost
- a target ratio between the values of Asset A and Asset B named $Tr$
- a scenario where:

$$ \frac{C_{AtoB}(Balance_A, q, cr)}{Balance_B + C_{AtoB}(Balance_A, q, cr)} > Tr$$

**How to calculate the value X of asset A to be converted into asset B in order to the expression below become true?**

$$ \frac{C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)}{Balance_B + C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)} = Tr$$

After solve the equation I found this:

$$X = \frac{Tr.Balance_B}{(1 - cr).q.(Tr - 1)} + Balance_A$$

But I am getting exactly the double of what I was expecting and I am not understanding why.

Comment: Why in the denominator of $$\frac{C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)}{Balance_B + C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)} = Tr$$ do you use the old value $Balance_B$ but the updated value $Balance_A - X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got my error.

Instead of:

$$ \frac{C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)}{Balance_B + C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)} = Tr$$

I should have written:

$$ \frac{C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)}{Balance_B + \color{red}{C_{AtoB}(X, q, cr)} + C_{AtoB}(Balance_A - X, q, cr)} = Tr$$

$\color{blue}{X}$ is the amount of asset A being converted into asset B so it will be part of the portfolio but as $\color{red}{C_{AtoB}(X, q, cr)}$ after the convertion.

Consequently, after solve it, instead of having:

$$X = \frac{Tr.Balance_B}{(1 - cr).q.(Tr - 1)} + Balance_A$$

I will get this:

$$X = \color{red}{\bigg[}\frac{Tr.Balance_B}{(1 - cr).q} + \color{red}{(Tr - 1).}Balance_A\color{red}{\bigg].-1}$$